# Prove $∪S × ∪T ⊆ ∪\{X × Y \mid X ∈ S, Y ∈ T\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm stuck at the following assignment.

Prove that $\cup{S} × \cup{T} ⊆ \cup{\{X × Y\mid X ∈ S, Y ∈ T\}}$ for all sets S, T of sets. **Show that in the first formula we cannot replace ‘⊆’ by ‘=’.**

Here's what I have:

Assume that $(u,v) ∈ \cup{S} × \cup{T}$.

Then $u ∈ \cup{S}$ and $v ∈ \cup{T}$, from which $u ∈ X$ for some $X ∈ S$ and $v ∈ Y$ for some $Y ∈ T$. From that it follows that $(u,v) ∈ \cup{\{X × Y\mid X ∈ S, Y ∈ T\}}$ since the former is the union of all $X×Y$ and therefore $\cup{S} × \cup{T} ⊆ \cup{\{X × Y\mid X ∈ S, Y ∈ T\}}$.

And the second part:

Assume that $(u,v) ∈ \cup{\{X × Y\mid X ∈ S, Y ∈ T\}}$ which is the same as $\{X_1 \times Y_1\} \cup \{X_1 \times Y_2\} \cup \ldots \cup \{X_1 \times Y_n\} \cup \{X_2 \times Y_1\} \cup \ldots \cup \{X_2 \times Y_n\} \cup \ldots \cup \{X_n \times Y_n\} $ where $X_n ∈ S, Y_n ∈ T$.

Then $(u,v) ∈$ of some $\{{X_n} × {Y_n\}}$. Consequently, $u ∈$ of some ${X_n} ∈ S $ and $v ∈$ of some $ {Y_n} ∈ S$. Therefore $u ∈ \cup{S}$, $v ∈ \cup{T}$ from which it follows that $(u,v) ∈ \cup{S} × \cup{T}$ and $\cup{S} × \cup{T} \supseteq \cup{\{X × Y\mid X ∈ S, Y ∈ T\}}$.

Finally this proves that $\cup{S} × \cup{T} = \cup{\{X × Y\mid X ∈ S, Y ∈ T\}}$ which is contradictory to the assignment's statement.

Is there a mistake in my reasoning or in the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two sets are indeed equal. Your first argument is correct. For the second you have the right idea, but your description of $\bigcup\{X\times Y:X\in S\text{ and }Y\in T\}$ has two problems. First, it assumes that $|S|=|T|=n$, when there is no reason to think that $S$ and $T$ are finite or have the same number of elements. Secondly, even if that were the case, it would be $(X_1\times Y_1)\cup(X_1\times Y_2)\cup\ldots\cup(X_n\times Y_n)$, not $\{X_1\times Y_1\}\cup\{X_1\times Y_2\}\cup\ldots\cup\{X_n\times Y_n\}$: you want the union of the sets themselves. The union of the singletons is just the set

$$\{X_1\times Y_1,X_1\times Y_2,\ldots,X_n\times Y_n\}$$

whose elements are the $n^2$ Cartesian products. The argument would be fine if you recast it slightly. Let $\langle u,v\rangle\in\bigcup\{X\times Y:X\in S\text{ and }Y\in T\}$; then there are $X\in S$ and $Y\in T$ such that $\langle u,v\rangle\in X\times Y$. But then $u\in X\in S$, and $v\in Y\in T$, so $u\in\bigcup S$ and $v\in\bigcup T$, and therefore $\langle u,v\rangle\in\bigcup S\times\bigcup T$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Gljiva: You’re welcome!